# how to automatically update a column in another table when an insertion is made in a different column in a different table in MySql using java

Tags: java, mysql

private void User_combo() {

```
    try {

        String sql = "insert into asset_update(User) select (Concat(first_name), ' ', (last_name)) from user";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("User");
            jComboBox_Users.addItem(name);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
}
```

it gives me the error "can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery();"

can someone please help me with this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PreparedStatement#executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate)

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE

`executeQuery()` for database QUERY statement(Like select)
`executeUpdate()` for database UPDATE statements
**update**

```
  String sql = "insert into asset_update(User) select (Concat(first_name), ' ', (last_name)) from user";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    int i = pst.executeUpdate();//since it is insert statement use executeUpdate()
    if(i>0){
          pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select User from asset_update");
          rs = pst.executeQuery();//since it is select statement use executeQuery()
          while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("User");
            jComboBox_Users.addItem(name);
         }
    }
```

Comment: so i should use executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery()?

Comment: @bagyei37 Yes.You have to use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()`

Comment: i tried that this time it gives no error but does not show or update in my jcomboBox

Comment: @bagyei37 to update in jcomboBox you need to execute select query again.I have updated the code for that.